# Is it possible to call an overridden to_s within class in ruby?

Tags: ruby

After making a change to one of the variables within the class I want the class' to string (`to_s`) method that I have implemented to be called with the new value for the aforementioned variable. I currently use:

```
class Car
   ...
   def ask_for_color_change(string)
     normalize = string.downcase
      if normalize == "yes"
        color = gets.chomp
        self.set_color(color)
        # tried with self.to_s also, doesn't work
        puts self
      elsif normalize == "no"
        puts "happy you like your factory color -> #{@color}"
      else
        puts "please reply with either yes/no ONLY"
      end
    end

  def to_s
    puts "New Car Details"
    puts "---------------"
    puts "Make: #{@make}"
    puts "Model: #{@model}"
    puts "Color: #{@color}"
  end

end
```

The `puts self` within the above method outputs  `#<Car:0x00007fabd18ddc98>`. From what I know this is the default `to_s` implementation. So, in other words, how do I call the overridden `to_s`within the class itself?

Answer (score 1):

I am now able to implicitly call `to_s` successfully within the `ask_for_color_change(string)` method by refactoring the `to_s` code like this:

```
def to_s
  "
  New Car Details
  --------------- 
  Make: #{@make}
  Model: #{@model}
  Color: #{@color}
  "
end
```

So, it had to do with the way `puts` is implemented. Comments as to the `puts` method's ability to still see the default implementation would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is already too much chaos in the world to allow someone to decide that their class doesn't return a String when you call `to_s`. The interpreter enforces this by calling `Object#to_s` instead if your implementation returns a non-string (or a tainted string).

From the source, edited for readability:

```c
VALUE rb_io_puts(int argc, const VALUE *argv, VALUE out)
{
    /* ... */

    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        /* ... */
        line = rb_obj_as_string(argv[i]);
        /* outputting line here... */
    }

    return Qnil;
}

VALUE rb_obj_as_string(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE str;

    // if obj is already a String, return it
    if (RB_TYPE_P(obj, T_STRING)) {
        return obj;
    }
    // call obj.to_s
    str = rb_funcall(obj, idTo_s, 0);
    // ensure it is a string
    return rb_obj_as_string_result(str, obj);
}

VALUE rb_obj_as_string_result(VALUE str, VALUE obj)
{
    // if str isn't a String use Object#to_s
    if (!RB_TYPE_P(str, T_STRING)) return rb_any_to_s(obj);
    /* ... */
    return str;
}
```