# Does Atom break ruby to_s override?

Tags: ruby

I want puts to return @value. The code is below:

```
class Tile
  def initialize(value, given=false)
    @value = value
    @given = given
  end

  def newValue(value)
    @value = value if @given == false
  end

  def to_s
    @value
  end

end

t = Tile.new(5)
t.newValue(6)
debugger
puts t
```

This results in the printing of just the object id, no variables.

Why? And what is going wrong here? Is it an Atom thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to call an overridden to\_s within class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582054/is-it-possible-to-call-an-overridden-to-s-within-class-in-ruby)

Comment: _"Is it an Atom thing?"_ – just run your code outside of Atom and see for yourself. (and no, it is not related to Atom)

Answer (score 1):

`puts` prints each argument by calling its `to_s` method. It also expects the `to_s` method to return a *string*. If `to_s` returns something else it ignores that value and prints the object's class and id instead.

In your example, `@value` is an integer. To fix your code:

```
def to_s
  @value.to_s
end
```